Displaying images stored in database in a spring boot web page
i have a question regarding how to display images stored in a database, i tried a lot of solutions, but nothing seems to help.
I can store images, however displaying them has proven to be hard.
I have no idea how to fix the issue
Any help would be appreciated!!!
owner.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Owners</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Owners</h1>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Profile Picture</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- Iterate over each owner -->
    <tr th:each="owner : ${owners}">
        <td th:text="${owner.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${owner.age}"></td>
        <td>
            <img th:src="|data:image/png;base64,${#strings.toString(owner.profilePicture)}|" alt="Profile Picture"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>


OwnerController.java
package com.gestion.g04.controllers;

import com.gestion.g04.models.Owner;
import com.gestion.g04.services.OwnerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class OwnerController {

    @Autowired
    private OwnerService ownerService;

    @GetMapping("/owners")
    public String getAllOwners(Model model) {
        List<Owner> owners = ownerService.getAllOwners();
        model.addAttribute("owners", owners);
        return "owners";
    }

    @GetMapping("/add-owner")
    public String showOwnerForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("owner", new Owner());
        return "add-owner";
    }

    @PostMapping("/add-owner")
    public String addOwner(@ModelAttribute Owner owner, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                return "redirect:/add-owner?error=file";
            }
            // Convert the file to a byte array and save it in the owner entity
            byte[] picture = file.getBytes();
            owner.setProfilePicture(picture);
            ownerService.addOwner(owner.getName(), owner.getAge(), file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/add-owner?error=file";
        }
        return "redirect:/owners";
    }
}


OwnerService.java
package com.gestion.g04.services;

import com.gestion.g04.models.Owner;
import com.gestion.g04.repositories.OwnerRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Service
public class OwnerService {
    @Autowired
    private OwnerRepository ownerRepository;

    public List<Owner> getAllOwners() {
        return ownerRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addOwner(String name, int age, MultipartFile profilePicture) throws IOException {
        Owner owner = Owner.builder()
                .name(name)
                .age(age)
                .build();

        if (profilePicture != null && !profilePicture.isEmpty()) {
            String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(Objects.requireNonNull(profilePicture.getOriginalFilename()));
            owner.setProfilePicture(profilePicture.getBytes());
            owner.setProfilePictureName(fileName);
        }

        ownerRepository.save(owner);
    }
}


Chatgpt couldn't help , i tried stack overflow as well

Storing images in a database is very inflexible and troublesome. Paths to images is another matter

@g00se what do you mean? in the project i'm supposed to store the images in a database and then display them later

It's really quite simple. Experience shows that's a bad plan. It's not practical

You can try saving the images as base64 in the database, and then show the base64 image in the gui.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1.0">
        <title>Base64 Image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,YourBase64EncodedImageDataHere" alt="Base64 Image">
    </body>
</html>

